# How can we export gridview as pdf and send as mail attachment

Tags: asp.net, itext

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        gridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();


            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender.com", "bharathidasan3010@gmail.com");// error here please help me
            mm.Subject = "GridView Exported PDF";
            mm.Body = "GridView Exported PDF Attachment";
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "GridViewPDF.pdf"));
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "youarethepower@gmail.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "<password>";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
        }
    }
}

==========================================
error : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`
```

Comment: Where does you error get raised (on which line)?

Comment: In mailmessage creation

Comment: MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender.com", "bharathidasan3010@gmail.com");// error here please help me

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quiet obvious.

The constructor for `System.Net.MailMessage` which you are using, accepts 2 strings, which it is trying to parse into a valid email address.
`sender.com` is not a valid email format.

Change it to something like `name@sender.com`